# **mismatched input '\r\n' expecting RULE_AS_A** error thrown while editing in story file of Jbehave Editor

Tags: eclipse, format

[Here is the attachment for the format that appears][1]

Currently I'm working on BDD framework using Jbehave. When started of with my story file writing it with Jbehave Editor. Following Errors occured

```
mismatched input '\r\n' expecting RULE_AS_A
mismatched input 'Scenario:' expecting RULE_I_WANT_TO
missing RULE_IN_ORDER_TO at 'Testing'
```

Here is my story file:

```
Narrative: Testing Connected Caseloads Module

Scenario: To verify the permission check for Connected Caseloads tab
Given User launch the application
When User provide valid user email id
And User Password
Then User should be logged in into Platform Application
Then Go to Configure tabs visibility
Then Check admin role is present by default
Then Add buyer role to Connected Caseload widget
And Logout of the application successfully
```

It would be helpful, If anyone assist me why the error occurs

**Note:** I'm able to run the script successfully, even though error is there in the story file

Comment: pls include your code with a clear problem statement here, that is the best practice on stack overflow, not only image with a brief intro. And Welcome to SO :)

Comment: @Patrik_P Hi! Patrik my apologize for raising vague question

Here is my actual problem. I'm working on BDD framework using Jbehave. 
In my story file I'm facing this issue, stating that 
1. **mismatched input '\r\n' expecting RULE_AS_A**
2. **mismatched input 'Scenario:' expecting RULE_I_WANT_TO**
3. **missing RULE_IN_ORDER_TO at 'Testing'**
4. **required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input '\r\n'**

I felf that the problem may be due to the symbol (format as appear in the screenshot attached), other than that I didn't find any issue in my Story file